# What would cause an iMac to have a white gradient glow on boot?

Tags: display, imac, startup

Searched the archives but didn't see this question asked or a similar instance when searching on Google and looking at Google images.  I have a mid-2011 iMac with stock internals and a AMD Radeon HD 6770M 512 MB graphics card.  Only on boot and after logging in on the right side of the monitor it has a white gradient glow going up the right side.

It's very noticeable on boot but after the monitor warms up (I'd assume)  it fades away.  I'll try to edit with a pic later this afternoon but I was curious to know what internal part would cause this issue and a solution?

I haven't moved the iMac in a long time and don't recall it doing it when it was moved but I only boot this about once a week.  I do have an SSD to swap out the stock hard drive this week but if I need a new part for the monitor if this isn't normal I'd like to know.

Comment: That's a symptom of a malfunctioning backlight or a failing of the LCD.   It's easy and not expensive to fix; [less than $200USD](http://amzn.to/2FAG5S2) and the glass is held in with magnets which after being removed, you can access the screws that hold the lcd in place.

Comment: @Allan ah thanks, will have to find that for the 27".